# How to make classList.toggle follow class's CSS

Tags: javascript, flip

I have a CSS class:

```css
.do-flip {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
}
```

When I click the button that results in this class being added to the element, the card flips, and when I click the button the back side that results in the classList.toggle, it unflips.

What it does not do is unflip (flip back) using the same transform-style and transition effect as the original flip. It simply presents the front instantaneously.

Comment: That's because you have removed the class containing the transition coding. You'll need to either set the default class to have the transition you want on returning or create a new undo-flip class and `classList.replace('do-flip', 'undo-flip')` and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have removed the class containing the transition coding. You'll need to either set the default class to have the transition you want on returning or create a new undo-flip class and `classList.replace('do-flip', 'undo-flip')` and vice versa.

```js
const card = document.querySelector('.card').addEventListener('click', (e) => {  e.target.classList.toggle('do-flip');
});
```

```css
.card {
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  transition: transform 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s; 
 }
 
.do-flip { 
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="card">card-flip</div>
```